# Making ẞ lowercase on MacOS bash

Tags: bash, macos, awk, character, tr

I have a problem with lowercasing ß character on MacOS. In all tools which I use for lowercasing (gawk and tr, awk has problems with encoding) it is not lowercased at all. Other special characters are lowercased correctly. Could anyone have some solution for that?

Examples:

tr

```
echo üäößÜÄÖẞ | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
üäößüäöẞ
```

gawk

```
echo üäößÜÄÖẞ | gawk '{print tolower($0)}'
üäößüäöẞ
```

Comment: Workaround: Does an extra  `| tr ẞ ß` work?

Comment: Do you know which characerset these characters apply to? e.g. share the output of `locale`

Comment: Interesting. `1E9E LATIN CAPITAL LETTER SHARP S` is from Unicode 5.1 standard, and `00DF LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S` is from Unicode 1.1 standard.

Comment: It should be noted that contrary to the other characters you show `ẞ` (capital `ß`) is a weirdo: it's **almost never used** and only exists for some very special cases (basically only in ALL-CAPS and even then it's usually represented as "SS" instead of that character). The reason for this is that `ß` can never be at the beginning of a word and as such never "naturally" gets capitalized. It even [has a dedicated Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_%E1%BA%9E).

Comment: `Does an extra | tr ẞ ß work?` - not for me, it looks like because `ß` has 3 bytes in utf-8 and `ẞ` has two bytes, and `tr` works byte-by-byte there so it works strangely, (like `echo 'abc' | tr 'abc' 'xy'`, repeats last byte). (side note: from [libunistring docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libunistring/manual/libunistring.html) `for German, where the LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S, when uppercased, becomes ‘SS’`, maybe that's relevant)

Comment: `LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=`
I was trying to use different values for LC_ALL and LC_CTYPE but unfortunately it is always the same.

Comment: @Thilo yes, it's working. But I was wondering, why it is working like that, and there is need for some workarounds. For my friends with Windows/Linux my code snippets works like they should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1: `perl`**

```
echo 'üäößÜÄÖẞ' | perl -CSD -ne 'print lc'
```

[image]

---

**Option 2: `tr`**

```
echo üäößÜÄÖẞ | tr ẞ ß
```

Because both `ẞ` and `ß` are completely 'different' [characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters), the common tools don't know the lowercase version.

As @Thilo suggested, you could use `tr [option] stringValue1 [stringValue2]` to 
 tell `tr` to 'replace' `ẞ` with an `ß`

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with GNU sed:

```
$ echo üäößÜÄÖẞ | sed 's/./\L&/g'
üäößüäöß
```

Comment: In my case it is not working, that is the output: `LüLäLöLßLÜLÄLÖLẞ`

Comment: @michaltalaga then you aren't using GNU sed as was stated is required. I'm not saying GNU sed would work, idk, but it wouldn't produce that output.